# Putting a List Inside the value of a map

Tags: list, map

I am getting an error

> Error is in expression '{!setGroupBy}' in page customjobapppage:

I tried multiple approach and I ended up with this: 
so this is how i Initialize my map

```
public Map<string,List<Job_Application__C>> groupedByPositionList{get;  set;}
```

and used trying to populate it like this:

```
public void setGroupBy(){
        for(Position__c p : [select Id , job_title__c from Position__C]){
             groupedByPositionList.put(p.Job_Title__c,new List<Job_Application__c>());
        }         
    system.debug('TESTER' + groupedByPositionList);
}
```

I am trying to insert an empty List of SObject but it is throwing me an error above , any thoughts about this?

I am a newbie currently on its 2nd day trying to code in salesforce , Maybe this is a newbie question . Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer , foolish of me my apologies.

I missed this Code

```
groupedByPositionList = new Map<string,List<job_application__c>>();
```